# Vue JS: Reset/Clear value from input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am building a search feature for my Nuxt Js front end and I need the input value to clear whenever the user has pressed enter to search. This is my current method and markup.

**Js**

```
methods: {
        searchTag: function(event) {
            var newtag = event.target.value;
            this.tags.push({name: newtag});
        }
    }
```

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search for tags..." v-on:keyup.enter="searchTag">
```

I tried adding event.target.reset(); but it didn't work, seems like such an easy thing but cannot find an answer anywhere, also want to stay away from using Jquery / plain JS as everything else is done without them and dont want to add it to the application for the sake of a tiny feature.

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer:

Adding a v-model to it and then setting that have a empty string seems to do the trick.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search for tags..." v-on:keyup.enter="searchTag" v-model="searchText">


export default {
    data() {
        return {
            tags: [
            ],
            searchText: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        searchTag: function(event) {
            var newtag = event.target.value;
            this.tags.push({name: newtag});
            this.searchText = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the searchText is set to  "" at the end of the search function.

Answer (score 2):

Just bind the input value to a variable and then clear it on the event like this :

```js
data{
  input : ''
},
methods: {
   searchTag: function() {
       this.input = '';
   }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search for tags..."  v-on:keyup.enter="searchTag" v-model="input">
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue is plain js. Of course you can use it.